# Is it possible to record iPhone calls with the latest iOS SDK 4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, avfoundation

Hi is it possible to record the audio stream during a voice call with any of the tools the latest ios sdk provides: AVFoundation, Core Audio, etc.?

If it is possible is there any documented way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: It is possible, but only on Jailbroken device. I have working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but during a phone call i believe the audio subsystem is unavailable to any apps, beit running in the background or not. 
in a JailBreak situation it may be possible but i still think not.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at the moment, and I doubt that Apple will ever add the feature (unless it's heavily constrained). It's a pretty big breach of privacy if someone exploits it.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are within their own sandbox, the Phone app is it's own app and therefore your app can't interact with it.
Audio is unavailable during a phone call (eg playing music/sound gets paused)

And background apps can only do so much is normal circumstances.

This will never be allowed, interception of Emails, SMS and phone calls. It's just too risky concerning privacy.

Imagine someone with bad intentions, recording all your phone calls, then sending them off to some server on the other side of the world.